# How to stop ad blockers from blocking?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-hosting, adblock, lazy-loading

Ad Blockers is blocking below items:

**Typekit:** ERR_ABORTED 500 (Request Block)

**Google Analytic:** net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

**And stops videos from playing:** net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

**lazyload.min.js:** 500 request block

I appreciate if anyone can help me.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you probably cannot.

The long answer is that these decisions are made by your clients. If the client has an adblocker that chooses to block certain resources, there is not much you can do as an application provider. You can try to obfuscate it by renaming the resource, serving it from a different URL path, etc. But, it is an arms race, and the adblockers will quickly catch on to your change.

Comment: And, anyway, I would say you should be respecting the wishes of your clients in this regard.